# Storing the value with the Ref, as long as it's not in the datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm have a `List<Ref<Entity>>`. I add new entries to the list like this:

```
entities.add(Ref.create(new_entry));
modified.add(new_entry);
```

When I store the entity that contains the list, I store the list itself and all the entities that are in the `modified` list. This works fine.

The problem is, that I have to work with the `entities`-list, while I add new entries to it. This requires iterating the list multiple times. The problem here is, that the refs in the list point to old entries (which are already in the datastore) and new entries (which are **not** yet in the datastore).

This causes the `Ref.get()`-method to return `null` for all the yet unstored entries in the list (the ones that are still in the `modified`-list).

I worked around this by doing this when inserting:

```
Ref<T> ref = new DeadRef<>(
        Key.create(data),
        data
);
this.entities.add(ref);
this.modified.add(data);
```

This way, I can mix stored and unstored entries in one list and `Ref.get()` always returns a value.

This works, but I have noticed that the refs in the `entities`-list *stay* `DeadRef`s when I store them to the datastore and load them in again.

Will this be a problem? Is there maybe even a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bad idea, although I don't know what specific problems you will run into.

The "right answer" is to save your entities first.

Edit: Also look at the documentation for `ofy().defer().save()`, which can prevent you from issuing a lot of unnecessary save operations.

Comment: I would have to safe them very frequently, which seems like a bad idea, too (especially with App Engines limited quota). Do you say it's a bad idea because it introduces possible inconsistencies, or is it not well supported by Objectify? Any other idea for a workaround?

Comment: It's a bad idea to use DeadRefs this way because you'll end up with surprise cases where you materialize a Ref and don't get what you expect. If you're trying to reduce the number of save()s, look at `ofy().defer().save()`. You can defer saving an entity many times and produce one datastore hit. Also, it goes into the session so a normal load() (or Ref.get()) will load the value.

Comment: `defer()` ended up doing exactly what I was trying to replicate myself. You should add that to your answer, I'll accept it.